# Query filter with CASE select NULL field [SQL Server]

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I simplify this into one WHERE clause with CASE WHEN statement:

```
@param varchar(1) NULL

if @param = 'Y'
  ... WHERE field = @param
else if @param = 'N'
  ... WHERE field = @param OR field IS NULL
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `case` expressions in the WHERE clause, stick to `AND`/`OR`.

Comment: oh, ok sir @jarlh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this : without CASE Expression

```
WHERE (@param='Y' AND field = @param ) OR  (@param='N' AND (field = @param OR field IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do it:

```
WHERE field = @param OR (@param = 'N' AND field IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify with coalesce, assuming NULL fields should be checked for 'N' param.

```
where coalesce(field, 'N') = @param
```

Of course, this may lead to strange results if @param can be something else than 'Y' or 'N'